# Junit - Test Hibernate Service Results

Tags: unit-testing, hibernate, junit, java

I have a DAO service which retrieves and saves data to Hibernate.
Could anybody point me to testing Methodology using JUnit for such service.

What is the best practice? When should I have passed test failed test and should I test exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test every possible path in your DAO. You would definitely use an in-memory database for your tests, such as `HSQLDB`.

One strategy would be to give the database some initial data in your `setUp()` method and clean it up on `tearDown()`, so all tests have a consistent working environment.

With these setup you can basically do everything... For example, if you want to test a `save()` method in your DAO, just add the new element and make sure that your table now has one more element. Moreover, fetch that element and compare it to the one you've inserted, it should obviously be the same.

Remember that **you should always test every possible path**.

Comment: Thanks for tearDown() and setUp(), but how many test should I do for each method? Should I have pass/fail and exception tests? I can realize that time test is very interesting test in matter of database testings.

Comment: Each path in the DAO method should be a separate test. For example, if one DAO method has an if-else block that sets a condition on a criteria query, it would make sense to have two tests for this method, each of which tests one of the paths through the if-else. If you have custom logic in a DAO method which will throw an exception, this also merits a test. However I wouldn't spend time testing exceptions thrown by the underlying framework (Hibernate, JDBC etc) as you are testing someone else's code rather than your own - and you'd end up repeating the test in N places

Comment: You should check the happy paths as well as the unhappy ones. For example, what happens if you insert two elements that are "equal" on a field you have declared as UNIQUE? Do you handle that case? What if I try to update a non-existent element? You have to be able to answer these questions in order to provide a solid piece of code. If you throw an exception to signal some error, be sure that the code is actually throwing it by writing a test that triggers that error.

Answer (score 2):

I would also look into using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to ensure that your database is consistent and test independent. They have articles on how to get started and a tutorial. There a quite a few [articles on IBM's DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/search/csass/search/?sn=dw&lang=en&cc=US&en=utf&hpp=20&dws=dw&q=dbunit) blog as well that you might want to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think using an in-memory database is often a good idea - for unit test. But the ideal is to combine fast unit tests with such a database with integration tests hitting the real database. There are subtle differences between, e.g., Hypersonic SQL and most production servers.

Consider using mocks for testing your error handling (i.e. mock the Hibernate session object and make it throw exceptions for certain operations)